# Selecting data by names/values in R

Tags: r

This is a generic question, but i am wondering if it could be possible.
Once that i have loaded my data in R, is it possible performs a statistical analysis in selected elements? Namely can i make a database-like query to select elements with specifics properties and then perform my analysis?
thanx

Comment: Yes. See "[r] how to subset" questions here on SO to get a feel of what's possible. See also `?"["`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select from your data with `subset`.
Check `?subset` for details.